# Dealing with system missing in R recode?

Tags: r, spss

I'm making the leap from SPSS to R and I was wondering how you deal with system missings...

For example, if I wanted to rewrite the following SPSS code into R:

```
RECODE income (1 THRU 6 = copy) (else = SYSMIS) INTO income2
```

I am able to write the following recode:

```
income_2018$income2 <- dplyr::recode(income_2018$income, '1' = 1L, '2' = 2L, '3' = 3L, '4' = 4L, '5' 
= 5L, '6' = 6L)
```

How do I deal with system missings (the 'else' statement in the SPSS code)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `.default` argument which will recode all values not explicitly named:

```
dplyr::recode(income_2018$income, '1' = 1L, '2' = 2L, '3' = 3L, '4' = 4L, '5' 
= 5L, '6' = 6L, .default = NA_integer_)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you convert the numbers to integer/numeric this should work automatically.

```
income_2018$income <- as.integer(income_2018$income)
#Or to change it to numeric
#income_2018$income <- as.numeric(income_2018$income)
```

It will return warning when converting non-numerics to integer before turning them to `NA`.

```
x <- c('1', '2', '4', '6', 'a')
as.integer(x)
#[1]  1  2  4  6 NA
```

> Warning message:
>   NAs introduced by coercion

---

As commented by @H 1 these would turn all numbers to it's numeric equivalent. If we are interested only in numbers between 1 and 6 we can do.

```
income_2018$income[income_2018$income > 6 | income_2018$income < 1] <- NA
```